# Problema ao ler arquivo

Tags: c, c++, arquivo

Estou escrevendo um código em **C++** e preciso ler um arquivo de distâncias que foi calculado em um outro algoritmo feito em **C**.

Este arquivo é mais ou menos assim:

100\n (número natural)
0.0000 58.25646 7.1556 \n5.1564 0.0000 44.00000...   -> uma matriz de floats

Segue o código da parte que lê o arquivo:

```
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    FILE *arv;
    arv = fopen("distancias_oliver30.txt", "r");

    fscanf(arv,"%d", &N_geracoes);



    float distancias[N_cidades][N_cidades];
    float feromonio[N_cidades][N_cidades];

    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < N_cidades; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < N_cidades; j++){
            fscanf(arv,"%d",&distancias[i][j]);

    }


    fclose(arv);
    ...
```

O problema é que o esse primeiro número natural ele lê corretamente, mas o nas distancias ele lê o primeiro elemento corretamente e o resto ele bota um número negativo esquisito (-107374176) ao invés de 58.25646, 5.1564...

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumindo esta declaração:

```
float distancias[N_cidades][N_cidades];
```

Isso está errado:

```
fscanf(arv,"%d",&distancias[i][j]); // ERRADO!
```

Este é o jeito certo de ler floats:

```
fscanf(arv,"%f",&distancias[i][j]); // CERTO :)
```

Comment: Puts... que erro idiota. Muito obrigado :))))))))))))))